# angular app runs in local tomcat but gives error in dev environment

Tags: angular, tomcat9, devserver

I am using angular 6 and deployed app in local tomcat. Others are able to access it from IE11. But when we deploy it on dev server tomcat few people are getting Expected identifier / Expected : error

Rest are able to view pages. Any guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was although other were using IE11 there emulation was set to IE 8